# How to use accelerometer in cocos2d 3.0?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am programming with Cocos2d 3.0 now, In Cocos2d 2.0, we can use the following code to add accelerometer to app, but this example was based on class CCLayer which has deprecate in Cocos2d 3.0, and UIAccelerometer also replaced by CMMotionManager in IOS 5.0, so I am wondering how to do this in Cocos2d 3.0? I googled for a while, didn't find anything useful.

```
-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        // ...
        self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;
        // ...
    }
}

-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer 
        didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
    // ...
}
```

===

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've written a tutorial on exactly this: https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/371/accelerometer-with-cocos2d-30-and-ios-7

You need to use the `CoreMotion` framework.

Comment: It would be nice if you could expand on this answer, how do I need to use `CoreMotion`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two problems in the tutorial example given above.

1. Single instance of `CMMotionManager`.
2. Acceleration data become +Ve or -Ve according to the orientation of the device. You also need to add Scene as observer of device orientation change notification.

If you don't want handle these overheads, you can use `CCAccelerometer` class. It solves both the problems.

## HOW TO USE

1. Add `CoreMotion Framework` in your project from Build Phases.
2. Copy `CCAccelerometer.h` and `CCAccelerometer.m` files in your project.
3. Import CCAccelerometer.h file in the Prefix.pch.
4. Implement the `<CCSharedAccelerometerDelegate>` in the CCScene where you want to use the accelerometer.
5. Create shared instance in init method by simply calling `[CCAcceleroMeter sharedAccelerometer];`
6. Start accelerometer in `-(void)onEnterTransitionDidFinish` by calling `[CCAcceleroMeter sharedAccelerometer]startUpdateForScene:self];`
7. Define delegate method `-(void)acceleroMeterDidAccelerate:(CMAccelerometerData*)accelerometerData` in your scene.
8. Stop accelerometer in `-(void)onExitTransitionDidStart` by calling `[CCAcceleroMeter sharedAccelerometer]stopUpdateForScene:self];`

You can find out the example project in [GitHub](https://github.com/sauvikatinnofied/CCAcceleroMeter).

Answer (score 1):

Here is example:

```
Device::setAccelerometerEnabled(true);
auto accelerometerListener = EventListenerAcceleration::create([this](Acceleration* acc, Event* event)
{
});

getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(accelerometerListener, this);
```

Also video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xk6lXK6trxU